# Memory Leak when Resizing Image before saving it to server C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, memory-leaks, memorystream

I am storing uploaded image file (IFormFile) using MemoryStream and FileStream.

When using solution like this, memory usage seems to be OK:

```cs
//projectFile is of type IFormFile
//without resize leak is not present
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await projectFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        byte[] bA = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Dispose();
        await fs.WriteAsync(bA, 0, bA.Length);
        fs.Close();
        bA = null;
        fs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to resize the image before storing it, the ProcessMemory usage in Diagnostic Tools of Visual Studio increases some 100MB, even that file is small jpeg, and memory is not recovered whatsoever:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await projectFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);//projectFile is of type IFormFile
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (var img = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
        {
            //memoryStream.Dispose();
            var resized = new Bitmap(img, ImageManipulation.ResizeKeepAspect(img.Size, 1900, 2534, false));
            using(MemoryStream memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                resized.Save(memoryStream2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                //resized.Dispose();
                //resized = null;
                byte[] bA = memoryStream2.ToArray();
                //memoryStream2.Dispose();
                await fs.WriteAsync(bA, 0, bA.Length);
                //fs.Close();
                //bA = null;
                //fs.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the ResizeKeepAspect is simply this:

```
public static Size ResizeKeepAspect(this Size src, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, bool enlarge)
{
    maxWidth = enlarge ? maxWidth : Math.Min(maxWidth, src.Width);
    maxHeight = enlarge ? maxHeight : Math.Min(maxHeight, src.Height);

    decimal rnd = Math.Min(maxWidth / (decimal)src.Width, maxHeight / (decimal)src.Height);
    return new Size((int)Math.Round(src.Width * rnd), (int)Math.Round(src.Height * rnd));
}
```

1. Why memory is not recovering, and how can I modify second example to resize and recover memory afterwards?
2. Why resizing the Image claims around 100MB of Process Memory, even that the file is simple screenshot?

----------------- EDIT --------------------
code looks like this after suggestions, still having problem with large memory allocation, but it seems to take less memory than before. I have used suggestions to not use byte[] and copy the memoryStream directly to fileStream. I would like to know, if there is still some space to save some more memory while resizing Image. As I have stated in the beginning, storing image without generating resized copy does not use all this memory. Shame it is not possible to purge these resources straight away.

Here is the updated code, still welcoming suggestions how to improve memory performace here:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await projectFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

    using (var img = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
    {
        memoryStream.Dispose();
        using (Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(img, ImageManipulation.ResizeKeepAspect(img.Size, 1900, 2534, false)))
        {
            img.Dispose();
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                resized.Save(memoryStream2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                memoryStream2.Position = 0;
                resized.Dispose();
                using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    memoryStream2.CopyTo(fs);

                    fs.Close();
                    memoryStream2.Dispose();
                    fs.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1 - what is the type of 'projectFile' (second row) so its easier to reproduce, 2 - the resize function does not seem to have any memory issues in it - instead i think its the "dispose" and "close" functions u r calling. the "using" statements should take care of this for u. maybe one of the disposed objects is disposed to soon so the other objects cant be disposed well and so the memory is still used. try dropping all the control functions and see if it helps

Comment: it is IFormFile

Comment: previously, I used using statements without .Dispose() or = null. When I noticed problems with memory, I have started testing with Dispose().

Comment: what do you mean by control functions?

Comment: 2 things: 1) the control functions are all those u used instead of "using" - meaning "close" and "dispose" 2) is the IFormFile disposed somewhere as well? its a stream that requires memory as well

Comment: I've edited code by commenting out control functions as suggested by you, and I do not dispose IFormFile nowhere. The result is the same - ~100MB of Process Memory is taken and it is not recovered after controllers'action returns response(Ok)

Comment: please dispose the IFormFile as well (use the "using" statement for it as well)

Comment: IFormFile is arriving to the endpoint as method parameter. How should I dispose of it? Create another instance of it?

Comment: `resized` needs a `using`. Also you don't need to copy the `MemoryStream` to an array, you can just do `memoryStream2.CopyTo(fs);`

Comment: and how do you Write FileStream without byte[] then?

Comment: @Charlieface how would you store that information in fs without byte[]?

Comment: The `MemoryStream` has a backing array, and it can copy that directly to `FileStream` as I said

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why memory is not recovering, and how can I modify second example to resize and recover memory afterwards?

When ASP.NET Core deal with high memory request, it keep the allocated memory. Thus it can deal the next similar high memory request without ask high amount of memory at OS (what is slow). It called the garbage collector server mode.

More information in : [Memory management and garbage collection (GC) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/memory)

You can disable this behavior in `.csproj` :

```xml
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Other method is explained in : [Runtime configuration options for garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector)

Try to disable the garbage collector mode and retest. If the memory is released, it isn't a memory leak, just a normal behavior.

> 2. Why resizing the Image claims around 100MB of Process Memory, even that the file is simple screenshot?

```cs
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // First duplication in memory
    await projectFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);//projectFile is of type IFormFile
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        //Second duplication in memory
        using (var img = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
        {
            // Third duplication in memory and uncompressed 
            var resized = new Bitmap(img, ImageManipulation.ResizeKeepAspect(img.Size, 1900, 2534, false));
            using(MemoryStream memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                resized.Save(memoryStream2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                // Fourth duplication in memory
                byte[] bA = memoryStream2.ToArray();
                await fs.WriteAsync(bA, 0, bA.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use very a little the stream, I am not sure. But I think the image is duplicated in memory several times. More over it is in Debug, the memory usage is raw (not optimized).

Comment: i am guessing you are right, using should take care of memory de-allocation, and indeed, each successive duplicaiton isdoubling the previous value, that could arrive to 100MB.

Comment: I am not conviced, however, that turning GC is good idea. I am torn between storing original size file and storing it with such high memory use.

Comment: @paddy, thank to specify this, my answer isn't clear. I was thinking of disabling only in test to check this point, not in production.